# List of ObjectIDs for an Algolia Index

Tags: python, indexing, algolia

Is there a way to retrieve all objectIDs from an Algolia Index?

I know there is `[*Index Name*].browse_all()` which in the docs say it can retrieve 1000 objects at a time but it retrieves the entire object rather than just the objectIDs.

I can work with pagination but would rather not and do not want to pull the entire object because our indexes are not small.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browse is the right way to go.

The good thing is that you can specify arguments while performing a `browse_all` and one of them can be `attributesToRetrieve: []` to not retrieve any attributes. You'll therefore only get the `objectID`.

Comment: Awesome! So apparently I can also add `{'hitsperpage' : 100000}` and it decreases the number of pages I have to go through which speeds up the process

Comment: No need to specify the `hitsPerPage` (anyway, the max is still 1000 per "page") the browse is designed to iterate over the whole index with a underlying cursor technology.

Comment: Yes I understand that browse_all will cursor through my entire index but by increasing the hitsperpage to 100000 on an index that currently has a little more than 100000 objects in it the retrieval time goes from an average of 1 minute 44 seconds to an average of 7 seconds.  I know their docs seem to say there is a max of 1000 but changing the hitsperpage seems to make a difference.

Comment: Oh maybe it uses the default `hitsPerPage` of your index settings (20) by default, and setting it to 100000 is interpreted as 1000 and therefore is way faster :)

Comment: haha 20 -> 1000 would also be much faster so either way I am happy!